# Custom GUI object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know how to create a simple XAML interface for a page, but I spend a lot of my time copying and pasting code since I have no idea how to create reusable XAML in a proper way, I know about styles but they don't quite fill the role. What I would prefer to do is to call them in the following way:

```
<CustomElement attribute1="bla" attribute2="{Binding somethingElse}"/>
```

Just like all the other GUI objects in the Silverlight framework.
Any help or hint would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two options. Both solutions act like any other Silverlight control. They can be inserted at random places in pages like you would normally insert a `Button` or a `StackPanel`. The option of choice depends on the specific reuse scenario.

1. Create a `UserControl`. These define their own XAML layout and are very easy to create. Consider looking at [ScottGu's tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/silverlight-tutorial-part-6-using-user-controls-to-implement-master-detail-scenarios).
2. Create a custom control. Custom controls also define their own XAML layout but through templating and styling. They are harder to create but support templating; this means other developers can decide that they will use the code behind your control, but specify a completely different layout. For more information look at [Silverlight templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189093%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

For a (much) better understanding, please look at [this page](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/user-control-vs-custom-control-in-silverlight-for-wp7) comparing the features of `UserControl`s and custom controls more in-depth.